# Error al iniciar el servidor HTTP Apache2 (en ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: apache2, sintaxis

Cuando voy a iniciar `apache2` en mi equipo me salta el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema:** Quiero modificar el archivo CAE.conf, que es un certificado normal y corriente, pero me da un error de sintaxis en la linea 12 donde tengo escrito:

```
SuexecUserGroup [usuario] [grupo]
```

**La raíz del problema**
Por más que he modificado, o he restaurado el archivo original, el problema de sintaxis me indica que es la palabra SuexecUserGroup, pero... No tiene sentido verdad?
Soy bastante "noob" en esto de ubuntu, pero tengo conceptos y pillarlo no me cuesta en gran medida, pero en este caso se me está haciendo bola.

Muchas gracias, que tengáis un buen día (sin conflictos de usuarios ni grupos) :)

Comment: apache dice que no puede encontrar o leer el archivostConcentrator-cert.pem que es un certificado en el archivo de configuracion de algun sitio eso esta en /etc/apache2/sites-available solo buscalo y elimina la linea o corrigela